# How to include a dynamic variable in javascript <script> element's "src" attribute in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

i want to add a javascript file in aspx page `<head>` section, but this javascript file name changes dynamically. Can i use a variable for src attribute in script element as shown in below example

e.g:

```
var jsFileName = "JScript1"`
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFolder/' + jsFileName + '.js"></script>
```

this is not working for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the case when `jsFolder/JScript1.js`, is the file loaded?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this

```
var fileName = "jsFolder/" + jsFileName + ".js";
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + fileName + "\"></script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rather than setting it to a javascript variable `jsFileName`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFolder/<%= ServerSideVariable %>.js"></script>
```

Hope you can do this way

Answer (score 1):

Ashoks answer is nice but you gotta be careful if you are doing some inline javascript. In-inline javascript you got to escape also the script-endtags slash `<\/script>` and it is also good practice to do so.

```
<script>
var fileName = "jsFolder/" + jsFileName + ".js";
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + fileName + "\"><\/script>");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete example. I was struggling until I found yours.